# Flexbox 100% Height Background Issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I've created a 2 column layout that should fill 100% height and functions as desired, but on Chrome / Safari if the content expands beyond the browser height the background on the right column cuts off when scrolling:

http://codeply.com/view/yCE7TYvKkV

[Screenshot of issue when scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w90Q4.png)
[image]

I can't for the life of me figure out how to remedy this, any insight appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should breakdown on how to replicate your problem, step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok So your problem is this div

```
<div class="row h-100">
  //Content
</div>
```

And you have applied height: 100%; to it which is causing the problem As your right and left column height is fixed to the window height.

So If you remove your h-100 class It will work fine.

Comment: Removing that class will indeed fix the background issue, but then the column loses its vertical height. The idea is that the right column would always stretch the full height of the window.

Comment: I was able to build on your suggestion to find a solution. Removing the class and adding the following:

    .container-fluid > .row {
    min-height: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    }